# subtraction of subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose I have two subspaces $V$ and $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that for another subspace $X$ we have $(V\cap W)\oplus X=(V+W)$

How can I find a basis explicitly for $X$ when I know basis for $V,W,V\cap W,V+W$ explicitly?

when $V,W$ is given, $V-W$ make sense?Like we know $V+W=\{x+y:x\in V, y\in W\}$

Comment: 1) No, "$V-W$" does not make sense, because usually $V+W = V'+W$ does not imply $V=V'$. 2) Maybe add some parantheses: $(V\cap W) + X\not=V\cap (W+X)$

Comment: Depends upon what explicit mean? Do you have the bases in the form of matrices of colomn vectors?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh, exactly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the bases in the form of matrices of column vectors, say $A$ for $V\cap W$ and $B$ for $V+W$ then put them together as $[A \ B]$ and make column reductions towards the right.

If $\dim(V\cap W)=k < \dim(V+W)=n$ then the first $k$ vectors is a basis of $V\cap W$ and the next (non-zero) $n-k$ vectors will give a complement (i.e. a basis for $X$) in $V+W$.

Comment: what does it mean by "column reductions towards the right", do you mean I need to find collumnspace([A B])?

Comment: Yes, but do you already have a basis for $V\cap W$ or do you need to find this as well? If you already have it, the easiest is probably doing Gauss elimination (but acting on columns rather than rows) on $[A\ B]$ as I suggested, to find the columnspace of $V\cap W$ and then the complement.

Comment: I don't think it is that simple. Think of two planes in $R^3$ that intersects in a line. When each of the two planes are given by 2 vectors it is in general not so obvious to find a vector in the intersection? (I would probably use taking orthogonal complements but perhaps you have a better idea?)

Comment: I have inbuilt commands in Matlab to find intersection of two subspaces when I know their basis

Comment: ok, that's practical. You may then simply try to compute linalg::basis(S) where $S$ is a LIST (not set) starting with the basis you found for $V\cap W$ and then all of the vectors spanning $V+W$. There are obviously too many but matlab reduces to a basis and I think (but may be wrong?) that matlab starts constructing the basis from the left, so that the one you gave for $V\cap W$ will stay and the remaining provides you the wanted complement.

Comment: basis for $V+W$ is simply given by colspace(V,W), regarding them as matrix..now I need a basis for complement of $V\cap W$, by the way $V\cap W$ is sitting inside $V+W$

Comment: yes, but my suggestion using basis(S) may actually give you a fast track way to compute the complement.

Comment: I am not understanding your S, what are theere in S?

Comment: If V and W are two lists of column vectors, you may try to use VW:=linalg::IntBasis(V,W) to get the intersection as a list of say k vectors, and then VsumW:=linalg::sumBasis(VW,V,W) to get a basis for V+W of say n vectors. If matlab (hopefully) calculates from left to right then the first k vectors in VsumW is the basis for $V\cap W$ and the remaining $n-k$ vectors should be a basis for a complement $X$.

Comment: Ah, I see!! thankx I will try tomorrow

Comment: please help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977558/how-to-find-a-basis-of-complementary-subspace-of-a-subspace